# Backdrop-filter in chrome has black border

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I tried to add the future-property `backdrop-filter` in chrome:

```
.glass {
    --webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px); /* chrome */
}
```

After activating it in `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` it finally works, but, I get a black border. Anybody an idea how to remove that border??

[image]

---

**Edit**

There is no zero-data-bug or something (tested with the SO-page):

[image]

If I take `3px` instead of `10px` the border is smaller, but not away:

[image]

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2x7t0p9p/) but better, you copy it local, because fiddle also just the right boder in example. Then it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just disable the blur? This looks like chrome is blurring with zeroed data outside the edge of the backdrop... I doubt you want to disable the blur though...

Comment: @SamPearman updated my post.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. If it's doing what I think it's doing, then it's a bug in Chrome.
Can you provide some more context? Some HTML or something?

Edit: Ah, never mind. I think I see what you mean.

Comment: Haha :D I tested that last two screenshots with the stackoverflow-page :D I will add some html/css

Comment: you edited in -> `if I take 3px instead of 10px the border is smaller, but not away`, but instead of `3px` you can also just do `0px`? if you don't want the border, as I don't know how it's calling the border, I'm probably thinking `border-radius`?

Comment: @KingReload Yeah sure, but then I also got no blur on the text :D

Comment: @MatthiasBurger have you tried `backdrop-filter: blur(1rem) saturate(200%); border-radius: 100%;`?

Comment: @KingReload yeah, makes no difference for the border

Comment: @MatthiasBurger also tried `filter` instead of `backdrop-filter`? Because I know `backdrop` has some bugs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37357933/7707749

Comment: @KingReload filter is the wrong property, yes...

Comment: That looks like a rendering bug in Chrome to me. It's trying to blur exactly as you told it to, but the renderer gets null or 0 data for the 10 or 3 pixels outside of the image, so when it does the blur, it's treating that null data as real data, and doing an RGB blur. If it was doing an RGBA blur instead, then this wouldn't be noticeable because the A channel would be completely transparent (although it would still be wrong on Chrome's part).
Looks unfixable to me without changing Chrome's codebase, as it's simply considering extra data that doesn't exist.

Comment: @SamPearman I added a fiddle-link if you want to test it local (maybe better local)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger If it helps a final possibility could be adding `background: rgba(247, 247, 249, 0.8);` like @sampearman described.

Comment: Yep, with the fiddle too, it works exactly as expected for my description above. It's a bug in Chrome, it's gotta be.
If you're having trouble visualising the problem, imagine that everything OUTSIDE the visible window is pure black. Usually you don't see it because the window ends, but when you blur...

Comment: background-property doesn't help :p mhh okay, thanks @SamPearman I think I need to reinvent the wheel with own CSS :( - I'd have been happy if the fail was on my own side :D

Comment: Yeah it works EXACTLY as I said. Change your fiddle's .front's width to 95% and the problem disappears because it's not considering data outside of the window. Change it to 97% and you see it lightly, several px in. It's a Chrome bug, 100%

@KingReload I doubt that'd fix it, but worth a shot I guess.

Comment: @SamPearman I tested it, but it doesn't give the blur effect what this question asks for sadly :( instead of using a `backdrop-filter` I now used `filter` which might work better, but still it isn't quite what was asked for, just mentioned it in the answer :)

Comment: @SamPearman that would work, but my bar is on bottom (1st screenshot) so I still got that border on bottom. I'd have to move the bar upwards with `bottom:5px`or something (else it also would look ugly with the color-gradient at cut left and right) - then it loses the blur-effect on the last 5px on bottom too. Otherwise it was a good approach.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger while this bug exists it's the only approach. If you REALLY wanted to get stupid with it, you could several concentric boxes with the blur decreasing as you get closer to the edge, but it still won't give you 100% the right effect.

Comment: **Just were here again after 3 years and checked if the bug still exists - and seems like the bug was fixed** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by rendering bugs in Chrome as described in comments above, and is unfixable as of now.

With a bit of mucking around, you can cheat it somewhat, but it doesn't behave entirely correctly.

[This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t82ozybe/1/) was one of my many attempts, but it only alleviates the problem. You can't entirely fix it.
By carefully controlling where the effect starts and ends, you can avoid chrome reading outside the bounds of the window and blending black, at the expense of a few pixels at the end.

```
    .frontcontainer{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .front1{
        position: relative;
        right: 3px;
        width: calc(100% - 6px);
        backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
    }
```

I also tried layering divs on top of each other and using a lighter blur towards the edge, which would have worked, while not being 100% right, but the layered background blurs don't interact correctly, or consistently.

Comment: If your site's background is a solid colour, you could actually get away with using tricks like this one. No chance if you need it on a rainbow though.

Comment: So I just give you the reps since your answer is the closest. I hope Google Chrome will fix this bug one day :D

Answer (score 1):

I used `filter` instead of `backdrop-filter`, but it might not be quite what you want it to be, but it does blur the text as expected, as the bug report in `chrome` might still remain, described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378512/backdrop-filter-extends-beyond-border-radius/37357933#37357933) post for the `backdrop-filter`.

```css
body{margin:0;}
    
        .front{
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20px;
            -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
            -moz-filter: blur(5px);
            -o-filter: blur(5px);
            -ms-filter: blur(5px);
        }
        
        .back {
            margin: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="front">
        <p> this is in the front </p>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="back">
    <p> this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back this is in the back </p>
    </div>
    
    
</body>
```

This would blur the front, but in my next example I have: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/king_reload/t5c045mq/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but this blurs the `front`-div instead of `back`-div on the position of the `front`-div :D

Comment: @MatthiasBurger I know, but thought I'd just show the option of `filter` :P maybe you could find a workaround for it

Comment: Yep, I will test a bit with `filter` - maybe there is a solution.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger have you looked at the jsfiddle yet? ;P

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit buggy :p it's an approach for a solution, but unfortunately, I can't use javascript. For security-reasons, the customers have disabled  javascript in their browsers. :( I need a pure CSS3-solution

Comment: @MatthiasBurger alright :) I hope there'll be a better solution then mine then! Hope you'll figure it out and let me know when you found one, I'm pretty curious

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still trying to deal with this, but I worked around it by using inset white shadows to hide the black blur to some extent.

So for a bar at the bottom of the window I have the following:

```
backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
box-shadow:
    inset 3px -2px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.6),
    inset -3px -2px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
```

It's not perfect but it almost hides the black glow caused by Chrome's rendering bug.

Of course this is Chrome-specific, you don't want the white inset shadow in other browsers which don't have this bug.